# Extracting pmid, nct_id, and publication type from PubMed xml in Python

Tags: python, pandas, xml, web-scraping

From xml file like this I try to extract pmid, nct_id, and publication type. Four sample files are [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1RvBfJm-9KhwbGbAymeKVmw4PUcAHRlBJ), one has NCT_ID.

```
<PMID Version="1">144418</PMID>
<PublicationType UI="D016428">Journal Article</PublicationType>
<AccessionNumber>NCT03070782</AccessionNumber>
```

Ideally I want to have a pd dataframe:

Expected output:

```
PMID    Publication_type  NCTID
1       Journal article   NCT03070782
2       Journal article   NaN
3       Journal article   NaN
```

But if somebody can tell at least how to extract for 1 file, I would greatly appreciate it too! I will figure it out how to put it into a dataframe.

Comment: You can use [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/) for parsing xml files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `glob` to iterate through all XML files
- Use `BeautifulSoup` to parse XML content
- Use `soup.find()` and `soup.find_all()` to find elements in the XML
- Use `.text()` to get the string from text node under the element
- Handle exception using `try` and `except` for `NCTID`
- Store content as a `dict` and append to a `list`
- Use `pd.DataFrame(<list>)` to create `dataframe` from given `list`
- Note that each `PMID` might contain multiple `Publication_type`, so, use `explode()` to split the list of `Publication_type` into multiple rows referred to the `PMID`

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

l = list()

for f in glob('*.xml'):
    pub = dict()

    with open(f, 'r') as xml_file:
        xml = xml_file.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")
    pub['PMID'] = soup.find('pmid').text
    pub_list = soup.find('publicationtypelist')
    pub['Publication_type'] = list()
    for pub_type in pub_list.find_all('publicationtype'):
        pub['Publication_type'].append(pub_type.text)
    try:
        pub['NCTID'] = soup.find('accessionnumber').text
    except:
        pub['NCTID'] = None
    l.append(pub)

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df = df.explode('Publication_type', ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

> ```
> >         PMID    Publication_type    NCTID
> >     0   144418  Journal Article     None
> >     1   272056  English Abstract    None
> >     2   272056  Journal Article     None
> >     3   349115  Editorial   None
> >     4   349115  Historical Article  None
> >     5   31893580    Clinical Trial, Phase II    NCT03070782
> >     6   31893580    Journal Article NCT03070782
> >     7   31893580    Multicenter Study   NCT03070782
> >     8   31893580    Randomized Controlled Trial NCT03070782
> >     9   31893580    Research Support, Non-U.S. Gov't    NCT03070782
> ```

Comment: Jay, can I ask one more question please? Very few articles have an NCT id from Clinical trials go. I have about 50 for 13000 xml files. How would you extract this, putting NaN for articles, where there are no such numbers

Comment: I updated the question and will upload such file to the folder

Comment: I uploaded such file as `nctidfile.xml` to the folder. I would greatly appreciate your help

Comment: @AnakinSkywalker, to handle `NCTID`, you can use `try` and `expect`. I've updated the answer, please see. Hope that'll satisfy your need.