# Extracting PubMed data in xml format from txt batches in Python

Tags: python, xml, web-scraping, txt, pubmed

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70433651/extracting-pmid-nct-id-and-publication-type-from-pubmed-xml-in-python) before and it was a perfect solution

A perfectly working code for multiple traditional `xml` files is below.

```
import pandas as pd
from glob import glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

l = list()

for f in glob('*.xml'): # Changed to .txt here
    pub = dict()

    with open(f, 'r') as xml_file:
        xml = xml_file.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "lxml")
    pub['PMID'] = soup.find('pmid').text
    pub_list = soup.find('publicationtypelist')
    pub['Publication_type'] = list()
    for pub_type in pub_list.find_all('publicationtype'):
    pub['Publication_type'].append(pub_type.text)
    try:
        pub['NCTID'] = soup.find('accessionnumber').text
    except:
        pub['NCTID'] = None
    l.append(pub)

 df = pd.DataFrame(l)
 df = df.explode('Publication_type', ignore_index=True)
```

It gave me my **desired output**

```
    PMID        Publication_type    NCTID
0   34963793    Journal Article     NCT02649218
1   34963793    Review              NCT02649218
2   34535952    Journal Article     None
3   34090787    Journal Article     NCT02424799
4   33615122    Journal Article     NCT01922037
```

The only thing I changed since - I extracted data, [using R and `easyPubMed` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/easyPubMed/vignettes/getting_started_with_easyPubMed.html). Data was extracted in batches (100 articles each) and stored in `xml` format in `txt` docs. I have 150 txt documents in total. Instead of ~25000 rows it now extracts only ~250.

**How to update the Python code above and get the same output**, when the input files have changed? I [add several `txt` files here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1yjlFLjQCYycnTsSyOIr8dtC3P_5vMrWl) for reproducibility. Need to extract `PMID`, `Publication_type`, `NCTID`.

Comment: @JayPeerachai, maybe you can help here again? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Previous code only builds a data frame for an XML of a *single* article not an XML of hundreds of articles. Therefore, you need to capture select nodes under every `<PubmedArticle>` instance in XML. Right now only the first article is being captured in each XML.

Consider etree's `iterparse` solution that is less memory-intensive to read large XML where you extract needed nodes between opening and closing of `<PubmedArticle>` nodes:

```py
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data =  []                               # INITIALIZE DATA LIST
for xml_file in glob('*.txt'):
    for event, elem in ET.iterparse(xml_file, events=('start', 'end')):
        if event == 'start':
            if elem.tag == "PubmedArticle":
                pub = {}                 # INITIALIZE ARTICLE DICT

            if elem.tag == 'PMID':
                pub["PMID"] = elem.text
                pub["PublicationType"] = []
                pub["NCTID"] = None

            elif elem.tag == 'PublicationType':
                pub["PublicationType"].append(elem.text)
                
            elif elem.tag == 'AccessionNumber':
                pub["NCTID"] = elem.text

        if event == 'end':
            if elem.tag == "PubmedArticle":
                pub["Source"] = xml_file
                data.append(pub)         # APPEND MULTIPLE ARTICLES

        elem.clear()

# BUILD XML DATA FRAME
final_df = (
    pd.DataFrame(data)
      .explode('PublicationType', ignore_index=True)
)
```

Comment: thanks for your time, a perfect solution. It is also very fast, which is great!